# User login issue on wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress

I have Wordpress multisite. I want the user who is registered from any of my network site to not be able to login to other network site.

For example, just now, if any user is registered on site1 then that user will login to site2 also with site1 login credential, so is there any way that user should not login to other sites?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you chose to differentiate your sites (users). IMO, you have two options:

1. Use subdomains:

   **site1.domain.com, site2.domain.com ... siteN.domain.com**

*This approach will require server configuration but it won't require you to do any development on the application side.*

2. Use custom URI paths:

   **domain.com/username1, domain.com/username2 ... domain.com/usernameN**

*This approach will require additional development at the application level*

Comment: Thanks Radu for your answer.
I am using **sub domains**. Can you please tell me which type of server configuration i have to do on server so that site1 users will not login into site2

Comment: @Maq my response was pretty general. I did a bit of research regarding Wordpress Multisite shared users and it seems that this is the out of the box functionality - users are shared between websites (the users table is common to all). Maybe you can find a plugin that offers separate users per domain. Have a look at this [article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303657/can-you-have-multi-site-wp-and-keep-users-separate) - maybe your question may have more visibility if addressed on wordpress.stackexchange.com.